# Sort numbers from file in C

Tags: c, sorting

I want to sort a file number by quick sort without using array. However, I don't know how can I replace a number at a specific position with another.
I'm starting by making this code:

```
int main()
{  

FILE* F1=fopen("file.txt","r+");
  int var1, var2, min;

while(fscanf(F1, "%d", &var1) ==1){
                min = var1;
                long pos1 = ftell(F1);
                fseek(F1, 0, SEEK_SET);
        while(fscanf(F1, "%d", &var2) ==1){
            if(min > var2)
            {
               //Replace the var2 by min in the file

            }

        }
        fseek(F1, pos1, SEEK_SET);
}
```

}

Please, it is possible ?

Comment: you need first loads the data in memory and next sort it.

Comment: No, no, no! If you want to sort data in a file, read it to memory first, then sort it. Replacing the usual swap with ftell/fseek mumbo-jumbo is insane.

Comment: Would not even work unless all the textual values have the same number of digits. In any case `ftell` does not tell the file position of the number you just read. The file pointer was advanced to point to its terminating character - not even the next number!

Comment: So, any solution suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, what everybody said: Read the data into an array of integers. Sort it. Print it back to the file or to another file.

Comment: How can I loads the data in memory to sort them without using table ?

Comment: I think by table you mean array. Why do you want to do that? Sorting in computer contexts is almost exclusively done to "tables" or similar data structures.

Comment: Yes, by table I mean Array !

Comment: does it have to be a c-program, or could you use a shell command as well (e.g. `sort -g -o test.txt test.txt` in linux)?

Comment: "without using array". Don't. Use an array.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reasonable way to do it without using an array. Here's what I would do:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef ENOENT
#define ENOENT 2
#endif

static int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        const int va = *(const int *)a;
        const int vb = *(const int *)b;

        return va > vb ? 1 : va == vb ? 0 : -1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        enum {PAGE_SIZE = 4096, INTS_PER_PAGE = PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(int)};

        int *arr = (int *)malloc(PAGE_SIZE);
        int *beg = arr;
        int *end = arr;
        size_t arr_size = 0;
        size_t max_arr_size = INTS_PER_PAGE;
        FILE *f;

        if (arr == NULL) {
                perror("malloc(3)");
                return errno;
        }

        if (argc < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\nusage: kwiksort input_file\n",
                        strerror(ENOENT));
                return ENOENT;
        }

        f = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

        if (f == NULL) {
                perror("fopen(3)");
                return errno;
        }

loop:
        for (; arr_size < max_arr_size; ++arr_size, ++end)
                if (fscanf(f, "%d", end) == EOF)
                        goto sort;

        max_arr_size += INTS_PER_PAGE;
        arr = (int *)realloc(arr, max_arr_size * sizeof(int));

        if (arr == NULL) {
                perror("realloc(3)");
                return errno;
        }

        beg = arr;
        end = arr + arr_size;

        goto loop;

sort:
        qsort(arr, arr_size, sizeof(int), comp);

        rewind(f);

        while (beg < end)
                fprintf(f, "%d\n", *beg++);

        fclose(f);
        free(arr);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use a `goto loop` where a simple `while(1)` loop would be enough? The sort one could be inlined instead of using another `goto`.

Comment: Personal taste; I prefer using `goto`'s for infinite loops and for end-of-program tasks/cleanup.